MyRazorPage.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder): no suitable method found to override (CS0115)
I am creating a razor page (.NET 6) for users to checkout, but when I try to have my razor page inherit from my base C# class, I get the error -
(CS0115) MyRazorPage.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder): no suitable method found to override
I am not sure what is going on since I have not overloaded any methods yet.  I did recently rename of of my projects so I am wondering if it is possibly a problem with my csproj file.
Any help is appreciated.
Razor Page:
@inherits CheckoutBase

<h3>Checkout</h3>

@code {

}

Base Class:
namespace MyBlazorProject.Pages
{
    public class CheckoutBase
    {
    }
}

csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.16" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyBlazorProject.Models\MyBlazorProject.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Your base class has to inherit from something that implements a protected BuildRenderTree(). The usual way is to inherit from ComponentBase:
public class CheckoutBase : ComponentBase
{
}


Yup super obvious answer, yet here I am. Thanks!
